# REGEX - matching ** on at least one line in a textarea

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textarea in which I need to validate that **at least one** line contains ** at the beginning of it.

Examples

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

**INVALID**

```
Line 1 
**Line 2
Line 3
```

**VALID**

```
**Line 1
Line 2
**Line 3
```

**VALID**

Is this possible using Regex?

Thanks in advance,

Marko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^\*\*/m.test(textareaEl.value)
```

The `m` flag means multi-line mode.  In that mode, `^` matches the beginning of the string, and the beginning of each line.  We have to escape * as `\*`.

Comment: Simply brilliant. Thank you Matthew!